# Categorical variables usage in pandas for ANOVA and regression?

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy, anova, hypothesis-test

To prepare a little toy example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

high, size = 100, 20
df = pd.DataFrame({'perception': np.random.randint(0, high, size),
                   'age': np.random.randint(0, high, size),
                   'outlook': pd.Categorical(np.tile(['positive', 'neutral', 'negative'], size//3+1)[:size]),
                   'smokes': pd.Categorical(np.tile(['lots', 'little', 'not'], size//3+1)[:size]),
                   'outcome': np.random.randint(0, high, size)
                  })
df['age_range'] = pd.Categorical(pd.cut(df.age, range(0, high+5, size//2), right=False,
                             labels=["{0} - {1}".format(i, i + 9) for i in range(0, high, size//2)]))
np.random.shuffle(df['smokes'])
```

Which will give you something like:

```
In [2]: df.head(10)
Out[2]:
   perception  age   outlook  smokes  outcome age_range
0          13   65  positive  little       22   60 - 69
1          95   21   neutral    lots       95   20 - 29
2          61   53  negative     not        4   50 - 59
3          27   98  positive     not       42   90 - 99
4          55   99   neutral  little       93   90 - 99
5          28    5  negative     not        4     0 - 9
6          84   83  positive    lots       18   80 - 89
7          66   22   neutral    lots       35   20 - 29
8          13   22  negative    lots       71   20 - 29
9          58   95  positive     not       77   90 - 99
```

Goal: figure out likelihood of `outcome`, given `{perception, age, outlook, smokes}`.

Secondary goal: figure out how important each column is in determining `outcome`.

Third goal: prove attributes about distribution (here we have randomly generated, so a random distribution should imply the [null hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypothesis) is true?)

---

Clearly these are all questions findable with [statistical hypothesis testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance). What's the right way of answering these questions in pandas?

Comment: One-hot encoder and softmax?

Comment: Tempted to just build out a NN for this in TensorFlow. However, I do want to get p-values and all also. So will likely end up with two approaches, the p-value one seems ripe for pandas/statsmodel/numpy/researchpy. How am I meant do this?

Comment: you've asked an important question but now you're digressing from it. Suggest to forget about building models for now and rather focus on **statistically correct approach** for the `categorical variable treatment`. The question can further be enriched by asking **how to measure the interplay between categorical and continuous variables**. Think about it.

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for [one versus all classification](https://utkuufuk.com/2018/06/03/one-vs-all-classification/). For your predictors you can use pd.get_dummies or one hot encoder from sklearn.

Comment: linear regression from statsmodels will give you p-values for each feature. If you're looking for confidence in the regression prediction take a look at this: https://docs.seldon.io/projects/alibi/en/v0.2.0/methods/TrustScores.html, maybe you can adapt it for regression instead of classification

Answer (score 6):

Finding out likelihood of `outcome` given columns and Feature importance (1 and 2)

**Categorical data**

As the dataset contains categorical values, we can use the [`LabelEncoder()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) to convert the categorical data into numeric data.

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

enc = LabelEncoder()
df['outlook'] = enc.fit_transform(df['outlook'])
df['smokes'] = enc.fit_transform(df['smokes'])
```

**Result**

```py
df.head()

   perception  age  outlook  smokes  outcome age_range
0          67   43        2       1       78     0 - 9
1          77   66        1       1       13     0 - 9
2          33   10        0       1        1     0 - 9
3          74   46        2       1       22     0 - 9
4          14   26        1       2       16     0 - 9
```

Without creating any model, we can make use of the `chi-squared test`, `p-value` and `correlation matrix` to determine the relation.

**Correlation matrix**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

corr = df.iloc[:, :-1].corr()
sns.heatmap(corr,
            xticklabels=corr.columns,
            yticklabels=corr.columns)
plt.show()
```

[image: Correlation matrix]

**Chi-squared test and p-value**

```py
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

res = chi2(df.iloc[:, :4], df['outcome'])
features = pd.DataFrame({
    'features': df.columns[:4],
    'chi2': res[0],
    'p-value': res[1]
})
```

**Result**

```py
features.head()

     features         chi2        p-value
0  perception  1436.012987  1.022335e-243
1         age  1416.063117  1.221377e-239
2     outlook    61.139303   9.805304e-01
3      smokes    57.147404   9.929925e-01
```

Randomly generated data, so null hypothesis is true. We can verify this by trying to fit a normal curve to the `outcome`.

**Distribution**

```py
import scipy as sp

sns.distplot(df['outcome'], fit=sp.stats.norm, kde=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: Distribution]

From the plot we can conclude that the data does not fit a normal distribution (as it is randomly generated.)

**Note:** As the data is all randomly generated, you results can vary, based on the size of the data set.

**References**

- [Hypothesis testing](https://towardsdatascience.com/hypothesis-testing-how-to-determine-significance-ce3991c5db53)
- [Feature selection](https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-selection-techniques-in-machine-learning-with-python-f24e7da3f36e)

Comment: For the categorical data encoding one could also use [`pd.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html).

Comment: `get_dummies` only gives me 0 or 1, here I have 3 options. Thanks @skillsmuggler, so I should take it that these [p-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value#Usage)s indicate that the columns are independent; and that the [χ² test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test#Example_chi-squared_test_for_categorical_data) values don't fit the [χ²-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution), so is unable to reject the [null hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypothesis)? - Finally your correlation matrix shows a strong diagonal, and is therefore true?

Comment: `get_dummies` does [OneHot encoding](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f). It splits a single categorical column into a binary (0/1) column of each factor.

Comment: You are right about the `null hypothesis`. The diagonal of the correlation matrix must not be considered. We only consider the `upper or lower triangle` in the correlation matrix. The diagonal elements correspond to the `coefficient of correlation` between the same column and is always `1`. [Reference](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/correlation-matrix/)